# Shifted results in pandas rolling mean

Tags: python, pandas, mean

In the (5 first rows) result below, you can see `Freq` column and the rolling means (3) column `MMeans` calculated using pandas:

```
    Freq      MMeans
0    215         NaN
1    453         NaN
2    277  315.000000
3     38  256.000000
4      1  105.333333
```

I was expecting `MMeans` to start at index 1 since 1 is the mean of (0-1-2). Is there an option that I am missing with `rolling` method?

*edit 1*

```
print(pd.DataFrame({
    'Freq':eff,
    'MMeans': dF['Freq'].rolling(3).mean()}))
```

*edit 2*
Sorry @Yuca for not being as clear as I'd like to. Next is the columns I'd like pandas to return :

```
    Freq      MMeans
0    215         NaN
1    453  315.000000
2    277  256.000000
3     38  105.333333
4      1   29.666667
```

which are not the results returned with `min_periods=2`

Comment: without looking at your syntax it is difficult to know what you did. what value did you use for `min_periods`?

Comment: how can you get 29 on the last row? also, by using the same logic as for the star of you df, your last row should be NAN

Comment: The list I gave was a partial one, the complete is much more longer. Here is a link with a little longer view of the list and [my code](https://huit.re/mmob) to produce what I was expecting.

Answer (score 3):

use `min_periods =1`

```
df['rol_mean'] = df['Freq'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean()
```

output:

```
   Freq      MMeans    rol_mean
0   215         NaN  215.000000
1   453         NaN  334.000000
2   277  315.000000  315.000000
3    38  256.000000  256.000000
4     1  105.333333  105.333333
```

Comment: sorry, I accepted your answer but this is not excatly what I expect:
`MMeans` column should begin with `NaN` then 315.000000 etc.
As I said in my question, I'd like numbers to begin at index 1.